# Jupyter: converting R notebook with percent sign to PDF

Tags: r, jupyter

**Problem: Jupyter with R doesn't convert to PDF. 
Cause: a % sign isn't escaped in the latex conversion phase.**
I have a solution, but I'm hoping there is something better/easier/more permanent.

I have recreated my issue in simpler form to highlight it better. Basically, I run the following in Jupyter (with the R kernel):

```
description <- data.frame("variable"= c("female",
                                        "phsrank",
                                        "BA"),
                          "label"   = c("=1 if female",
                                        "% high school rank",
                                        "=1 if Bachelor's degree"))
description
```

This outputs the following table:

```
    variable    label
1   female      =1 if female
2   phsrank     % high school rank
3   BA          =1 if Bachelor's degree
```

Then I save the notebook as Breaking_pdf_R.ipynb, and select File > Dowload As > PDF via LaTeX. A new browser window opens with the following:

**500 : Internal Server Error**

**The error was:**

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed
```

Next, I tried the command line:

```
ipython nbconvert --to pdf Breaking_pdf_R.ipynb
```

A latex error came through in the output:

```
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate

l.242   3 &
           BA & =1 if Bachelor's degree\\
?
! Emergency stop.
<recently read> \endtemplate

l.242   3 &
           BA & =1 if Bachelor's degree\\
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Followed by the error:

```
raise RuntimeError("PDF creating failed")
RuntimeError: PDF creating failed
```

The pdf conversion failed because of an issue with latex. I was able to convert my .ipybn file to .tex though with the command:

```
ipython nbconvert --to latex Breaking_pdf_R.ipynb
```

Viewing the latex code, I noticed that the table output (for the dataframe) had an **un-escaped %**. Since % is used for comments in latex, this was fouling up the table.

```
    \begin{tabular}{r|ll}
  & variable & label\\
\hline
    1 & female & =1 if female\\
    2 & phsrank & % high school rank\\
    3 & BA & =1 if Bachelor's degree\\
\end{tabular}
```

**I escaped the percent (changed % to \%) and then converted the file with pdflatex (using Texmaker), and finally the pdf was successful, and I have a beautiful table.**

**I'm wondering if there is a better fix for this, rather than having to go through all of the above steps, and trying to interpret the errors.**

As a side note, **I found that this is only a problem with R. When I do the equivalent code in Jupyter with Python, I get an uglier table in the pdf output (because it doesn't use tabular in the latex, unlike in the R example), but the % is automatically escaped.**

With Jupyter and a Python kernel:

```
import pandas as pd
description = pd.DataFrame({"variable": ["female",
                                        "phsrank",
                                        "BA"],
                            "label"   : ["=1 if female",
                                        "% high school rank",
                                        "=1 if Bachelor's degree"]})
description
```

Output:

```
    label                   variable
0   =1 if female            female
1   % high school rank      phsrank
2   =1 if Bachelor's degree BA

ipython nbconvert --to pdf Breaking_pdf_py.ipynb
```

The above works just fine (where Breaking_pdf_py.ipynb is my Jupyter python file).

Comment: File a bug report and use RMarkdown and knitr for now?

Comment: I just filed a bug (https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/254) on the Jupyter nbconvert page. I found that there are also issues with the "#" symbol and the ">" and "<" symbols.